# Dante Server not Installing

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dpkg, socks5

I'm a beginner at Ubuntu and have made quite a silly mistake installing Dante Server: I accidentally installed an old version of Dante server on Ubuntu 20.04 (through wget - dante-server_1.4.1-1_amd64.deb). I tried to uninstall it and used all kinds of force uninstall methods through apt-get, and rebooting the machine, and updating sudo apt-get.

When I try and install the new version of Dante server now, I get the same errors over and over again. Here's the error log.

```
root@vct2:~# sudo dpkg -i dante-server_*.deb
Selecting previously unselected package dante-server.
(Reading database ... 175039 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dante-server_1.4.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dante-server (1.4.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack dante-server_1.4.2+dfsg-7build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dante-server (1.4.2+dfsg-7build3) over (1.4.1-1) ...
More than one copy of package dante-server has been unpacked
 in this run !  Only configuring it once.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dante-server:
 dante-server depends on libc6 (>= 2.33); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2.

dpkg: error processing package dante-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dante-server
```

I really hope someone can help me. It's quite late in my region now so there may be a big delay for me to respond. I'm also new to Stack Overflow but have found it super helpful in the past solving Ubuntu issues in the past.

Comment: The problem is with the version of libc6 that you have.  Dante is apparently looking for version 2.33, which is available in Ubuntu 21.04 (not 20.04).  You could try removing the dante package, with `sudo dpkg --remove dante-server`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yep, that fixed my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Di Nada - I will write that up as an answer then - please mark it as accepted, so that if someone is looking for a similar problem, they can see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the version of libc6 that you have. Dante is apparently looking for version 2.33, which is available in Ubuntu 21.04 (not 20.04).

You could try removing the dante package, with

```
sudo dpkg --remove dante-server
```

Then...

There is a version of dante server in the standard repositories.  I do not know if this version (1.4.2) has some features that you need, but it is compiled for Ubuntu 20.04